# Get two data with one loop

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I get two params from some form in a controller like this:

```
$productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productId');
$productQtys = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty');
```

Result:

```
[productId] => Array(
               [0] => 106
               [1] => 107
               [2] => 108
               [3] => 109
               )    
[qty] => Array(
               [0] => 4
               [1] => 3
               [2] => 2
               [3] => 1
              )
```

Good, now i want to get in **each loop** a `productId` and `qty`

I tested this it works for product but i can't get a qty :

```
foreach($productIds as $prod) {
    //some code...
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                     ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                     ->load($prod);
    $cart->addProduct($product->getId(), $qty) // here how i get the $qty of each product, if i put it manually it works, 2 for exemple, it add 2 for all products

}
```

Comment: If you want to connect the `id`s and the `qty`s so, that for every `id` there is a corresponding `qty` (or the other way round, it doesn't matter), you should create an associative array with the values of the `$productId` as keys and the values of `qty` as values, so you get something like: `[106 => 4, 107 => 3, ...]`. You then can access both the values, the `id` as the key and `qty` as the values from within your `foreach()`.

Comment: Good idea, how do to associate the two ? `array_merge` ? if you can answer this, it would be good

Comment: The function you are looking for is [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
array_combine($productIds,$productQtys)
```

Result:

```
array(
       [1639] => 6
       [1640] => 4
       [1641] => 3
       [1646] => 2
)

//Thanks to @Tobias F
```

Comment: This will give you the result you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If your keys are corresponding then you can extend your foreach to the key=>value construction. Then you can use the key in in the qty array directly. Didn't test it but here it goes:

```
foreach($productIds as $key => $prod) {

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                     ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                     ->load($prod);
    $cart->addProduct($product->getId(), $qty[$key]) 
}
```